# Have an issue with JavaScript, AJAX code displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I need some tips from you out there to come over a good solution on my problem with JavaScript, AJAX and JSON data. I want to fill a generic set with barcharts (I am using HighCharts) on my web page. The data is in JSON format which from the start I only used date and value as pair data set. The solution works fine of I had only one bar chart it, but I have a lot of charts on my page and I need to show all of them (up to twelve).

Now I want to adjust for displaying more than one graph. In the code below the DataMacro array works fine with the chart. It also has a hard coded ID matching a . Now I have a series of  in the page like id=barchart11, id=barchar21, and so on. In the dataset I have made a tag called PanelCodeUI that I am going to use looping through the dataset. The problem is how to do that. The each-loop will now fill in all date,value for all vessels.

And further it I need to restructure the function which is displaying the barchart. The best thing would be to call a function with a data array and panelCodeUI id just replacing the name of the barchart and set in the datamacro as is. But I don’t know how to do this. The data is mixed between all vessels and I need to collect all data before sending to a function. So is the problem with AJAX and JavaScript with is asynchron. I need to ensure that it behaves correctly and fast.

Maybe I need to change my dataset, or I need to do this in several step like finding all vessel IDs then do another AJAX call to get date,value pair from a vessel and then displaying. I hope there is a way to do this with this data set and hope somebody can help me on this

Here is a bit of the JSON data set:

```
[
{"__type":"Demo.Entities.OilProductionLast5DaysEntity","Date":1465084800000,"Value":844,"VesselId":1,"SectorId":2,"PanelCodeUI":"21","VesselCodeUI":"21","VesselSorting":1},

{"__type":"Demo.Entities.OilProductionLast5DaysEntity","Date":1465084800000,"Value":8720,"VesselId":4,"SectorId":1,"PanelCodeUI":"11","VesselCodeUI":"12","VesselSorting":2},

{"__type":"Demo.Entities.OilProductionLast5DaysEntity","Date":1465084800000,"Value":948,"VesselId":5,"SectorId":1,"PanelCodeUI":"11","VesselCodeUI":"11","VesselSorting":1},

{"__type":"Demo.Entities.OilProductionLast5DaysEntity","Date":1465084800000,"Value":0,"VesselId":6,"SectorId":3,"PanelCodeUI":"31","VesselCodeUI":"31","VesselSorting":1},

{"__type":"Demo.Entities.OilProductionLast5DaysEntity","Date":1465171200000,"Value":2067,"VesselId":1,"SectorId":2,"PanelCodeUI":"21","VesselCodeUI":"21","VesselSorting":1}
]
```

And here is the JavaScript code so far:

```
$(function () {
            var datamacro = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '../Services/HighChartService.asmx/GetOilProductionLast5DaysByActiveVessels',
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (seriedata) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(seriedata.d));
                    var productions = seriedata.d;

                    $.each(productions, function (index, productions) {
                        var yval = productions.Value;
                        var xval = productions.Date;
                        var x = [xval, yval];
                        datamacro.push(x);

                        //alert("productions Name: " + productions.Date + "\nID: " + productions.Value);
                    });

                    $(function () {
                        //var bchart = '#barchart' + vesselindex.toString();

                        // want this to be looped with generic names like #barchart11, #barchart21, #barchart31 and so on
                        $('#barchart11').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'LAST FIVE DAYS'
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: ''
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                type: "datetime",
                                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                                labels: {
                                    rotation: -45,
                                    align: 'right'
                                },
                                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                                    day: '%e. %b',
                                },
                                //crosshair: true
                            },
                            credits: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                labels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: null
                                }

                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<br/>' + ' in barrels: ' + this.y;
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                }, series: {
                                    pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
                                    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                //name: '',
                                showInLegend: false,
                                data: datamacro,
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    rotation: -90,
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                    align: 'right',
                                    format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                                    y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: '13px',
                                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    });
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you would like to draw a chart for each different panelCodeUI ?

If that's the case, change your code after AJAX success with that :

```
var productions = seriedata.d;

var listPanelCodeUI = productions.map(function(p){return p.PanelCodeUI}).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
//listPanelCodeUI : [21,11,31]

listPanelCodeUI.sort();

listPanelCodeUI.forEach(function(e){

   datamacro = [];

   //Create a div for each panelCodeUI
   $("body").append("<div id='barchart" + e + "'></div>");

   var divId = "#barchart"+e;

   //Filter productions for specific panelCodeUI
   var data = productions.filter(function(p){return p.panelCodeUI === e});

   data.forEach(function(d){
      var yval = d.Value;
      var xval = d.Date;
      var x = [xval, yval];
      datamacro.push(x);
   });

  $(function () {
      $(divId).highcharts({

      ...

      })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what you need to parse your data:

```
charts = [];
$.each(productions.map(function(el) {
    return el.PanelCodeUI;
  }).filter(function(el, index, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(el) === index;
  }), function(index,PanelCodeUI) {
    var serie = productions.filter(function(el) {
      return el.PanelCodeUI === PanelCodeUI;
    });
    $.each(serie, function(index, production) {
      datamacro.push([production.Value, production.Date]);
    });
    drawChart('#barchart' + PanelCodeUI, 'LAST FIVE DAYS', datamacro);
  });
```

Also i made this helper function to create the charts:

```
function drawChart(containerID, chartTitle, data) {
  charts.push(new Highchart.Chart({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      renderTo: containerID
    },
    title: {
      text: chartTitle
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        align: 'right'
      },
      dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
        day: '%e. %b',
      },
      //crosshair: true
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      }

    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<br/>' + ' in barrels: ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      },
      series: {
        pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
      }
    },
    series: [{
      //name: '',
      showInLegend: false,
      data: data,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        rotation: -90,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'right',
        format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
        style: {
          fontSize: '13px',
          fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
      }
    }]
  }));
}
```

Comment: Hi again. I am testing Your code. I got errors becase of the first line in drawChart function. Charts is not defined. is it another array of highchart bar Charts so I need to define charts[] somewhere outside this funcion?

Comment: My bad, forgot to add that. Yes it's just an array to store all the carts if you need to do something afterwards. If you don't plan on modifying the chart after being drawn you can just remove the `.push()`